# When i load localhost:3000 my scripts load in fine and work the moment i redirect to localhost:3000/weather/new they dont load in

Tags: javascript, html

Scripts won't load when I redirect to a new URL beside the standard localhost:3000

tried removing meta tags, also turned off adblockers

```
<head>
 <title>Weather Report</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="Flatty Weather Report template Responsive,    Login form web template,Flat Pricing tables,Flat Drop downs  Sign up Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Login sign up Responsive web template, SmartPhone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyEricsson, Motorola web design" />
 <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
 <!-- Custom Theme files -->
 <link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"  /> 
 <link href="/css/search.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<!-- //Custom Theme files -->
<!-- web font -->
 <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- //web font -->
<!-- js -->   `enter code here`
 <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/skycons.js"></script> <!-- skycons-icons -->   
<!-- //js -->  
</head>
```

I expect the scripts to load in when going to a different URL

**Error messages:**
The script from `“http://localhost:3000/weather/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js”` was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/HTML”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
new
Loading failed for the  with source `“http://localhost:3000/weather/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js”`

new:23:1
The script from “http://localhost:3000/weather/%7B%7Basset('/js/skycons.js')%7D%7D” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/HTML”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.
new
Loading failed for the  with source `“http://localhost:3000/weather/%7B%7Basset('/js/skycons.js')%7D%7D”`

new:24:1
ReferenceError: Skycons is not defined
new:135:19
ReferenceError: Skycons is not defined

Comment: ```<script src="/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>``` and ```<script src="/js/skycons.js"></script>``` use absolute url ... means starting with a slash '/'

Comment: Thank you this solved the problem